# In Cocoa Touch can a datasource be referred to as the model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Just wondering if a datasource in Cocoa Touch can be referred to a the model or part of the/ model?

**Taken from a book I'm currently learning with:**
*“In a procedural design, you tell the table view what it should display. In Cocoa Touch, the table view asks another object – its dataSource – what it should display.”*

Using another framework ruby on rails when I wish to display data in the view my controller asks the model for what to display and then passes it to the view and the view decides how it's going to display it.

After reading that paragraph from the big nerd book I'm currently teaching myself with I'm wondering since the controller asks the datasource for what to give to the view to display can the datasource be referred to as the model? I'd like to clear this up before moving forqard.

I found myself rushing chapters without fully understanding things so decided to go back a few chapters until where I last felt comfortable and started studying again, taking my time.

I'd appreciated if someone could clear this up for me thanks.

Regards

Comment: If you are studying books, do not miss Mattt Thompson's [NSHipster-the book](https://gumroad.com/l/nshipster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the controller is usually set as the `datasource` there are many times good reason to set it to it's own class.

One good reason to do this is if a controller has several `UITableVIew`s, that way if statements in the `datasource` callback are not needed, separating the different `UITableView`s data logic.

But this probably should not be considered a data model since it directly interacts with the view.

Comment: So datasource is basically the middle man between the view and the model? Sounds just like a controller.

Comment: Yes, it is splitting the controller up based on functionality but it is specific to a portion of the functionality. Controllers are sometimes called "Interactors" (See "Uncle Bob"); he usually has separate classes for display and receiving input, essentially `IBOutlet` and `IBActions`. It is also possible to use the same datasource class in more than one `UITableVIew`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your dataSource is the controller and the controller manages a collection of models, or a single model, same as Rails. That being said, you can set anything as the delegate, and anything as the dataSource — it is just customary to set these as controllers that manage your models as an intermediary between the views and the data.

Comment: Ok so my view asks the datasource (typically a controller) for data to display and displays it how it wants. The datasource needs to get the data from somewhere so this is where my model comes in. So I take the datasource asks the model for data to give to the view when it asks. I this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The controller doesn't ask the datasource - the view asks the datasource. The datasource is a property of the view.

Many table views > many datasources.

So, no, tableview datasource is not synonymous with The Model.

Comment: I think I understand now. The datasource is basically a controller? It simply has data it has taken from the model ready to give to the view when the view asks for it?